# My new DKIM is in another format than I expected?

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, dkim

I am about to register a DKIM for a new domain. However, that format differs form what I expect. cPanel is giving me this:

```
default._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvbBZcUcajRf+nP+BSvhsa8roEcor2rf9oLs98u8HrqjZgpHQJ4frbA2C8OuRlPGN9JzZKpTmeeJg2eITeJXlQsc88xX0hqZCogDUeUcTLghDhw2Vd7q5AWG6mDcc3F2HJ0q5GwkYTS7d6D9nXCGcSE/M/F2pgwBe5MI5S9h60cr+XhHrK3uDCW3QNMj6jRDIW" 3o5WquA5/MmQJJ38BwMzn/7HJwcL6aJ5EnA3KlLi413kK820f4h2E+u4dAT5Kmua7x8Lx1ny7oEZH/MBQoEMq0s7XuDD+d0gR/0VCHvQ6PhZf4wOwzGIO6jn/Fb/pywAgQqZRglRGZLbcoHHQCIgQIDAQAB\;
```

Please pay attention to the placement of the double quotes - it is ended inside the p-string, and then theres another string after that. I'm having problems getting my DKIM to verify.

Shall I do something different than just pasting the "v= xxxx as text record?

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems normal.

- Each TXT value is of limited length – [0 to 255 bytes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3), not enough for a large RSA key. I'm not sure how DKIM deals with that...
- However, TXT records are **multi-valued**. `foo TXT "bar" "baz" "quux"` is valid. I think usually multiple values are joined into one when interpreting the record.
- In zonefiles, quotes are optional if the text doesn't have spaces or special characters, or if they're properly escaped (i.e. `foo\;` instead of just `foo;` works just as well as `"foo;"` does).

So what you need is a TXT record with the following two values:

`v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvbBZcUcajRf+nP+BSvhsa8roEcor2rf9oLs98u8HrqjZgpHQJ4frbA2C8OuRlPGN9JzZKpTmeeJg2eITeJXlQsc88xX0hqZCogDUeUcTLghDhw2Vd7q5AWG6mDcc3F2HJ0q5GwkYTS7d6D9nXCGcSE/M/F2pgwBe5MI5S9h60cr+XhHrK3uDCW3QNMj6jRDIW`

`3o5WquA5/MmQJJ38BwMzn/7HJwcL6aJ5EnA3KlLi413kK820f4h2E+u4dAT5Kmua7x8Lx1ny7oEZH/MBQoEMq0s7XuDD+d0gR/0VCHvQ6PhZf4wOwzGIO6jn/Fb/pywAgQqZRglRGZLbcoHHQCIgQIDAQAB;`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I am not sure that I fully understand. Will I just create this TXT entry:

name: default._domainkey


value:
"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvbBZcUcajRf+nP+BSvhsa8roEcor2rf9oLs98u8HrqjZgpHQJ4frbA2C8OuRlPGN9JzZKpTmeeJg2eITeJXlQsc88xX0hqZCogDUeUcTLghDhw2Vd7q5AWG6mDcc3F2HJ0q5GwkYTS7d6D9nXCGcSE/M/F2pgwBe5MI5S9h60cr+XhHrK3uDCW3QNMj6jRDIW" 3o5WquA5/MmQJJ38BwMzn/7HJwcL6aJ5EnA3KlLi413kK820f4h2E+u4dAT5Kmua7x8Lx1ny7oEZH/MBQoEMq0s7XuDD+d0gR/0VCHvQ6PhZf4wOwzGIO6jn/Fb/pywAgQqZRglRGZLbcoHHQCIgQIDAQAB\;

Comment: I tried adding the record exactly like you wrote it, but it doesn't seem to work.. Can I do anything else?